# Bower - Pinning to Major Versions Asks for Resolution

Tags: bower, semantic-versioning

Why is this asking me for resolutions when everything is pinned to `^` major versions? I imagine I'm doing something wrong in my releases on github because it only asks for resolutions on my repos and not for polymer which are two different minor versions.

I'm running `bower install` on this `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tylergraf/test1",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "test2": "git+https://github.com/tylergraf/test2#^0.0.3",
    "test3": "git+https://github.com/tylergraf/test3#^0.0.5"
  }    
}
```

test2 `bower.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tylergraf/test2",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "dependencies": {
    "test3": "git+https://github.com/tylergraf/test3#^0.0.3",
    "polymer": "git+https://github.com/polymer/polymer#^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

test3 `bower.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test3",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tylergraf/test3",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "dependencies": {
    "test2": "git+https://github.com/tylergraf/test2#^0.0.2",
    "polymer": "git+https://github.com/polymer/polymer#^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for test2, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) test2#^0.0.2 which resolved to 0.0.2 and is required by test3#0.0.3, test3#0.0.5
    2) test2#^0.0.3 which resolved to 0.0.3 and is required by test1

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 2

Unable to find a suitable version for test3, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) test3#^0.0.3 which resolved to 0.0.3 and is required by test2#0.0.3
    2) test3#^0.0.5 which resolved to 0.0.5 and is required by test1

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug into bower and got to semver.

Major zero is a special case in the semver spec, anything less than `0.1.0` will always resolve exactly to itself.

`^0.0.1` always points to `0.0.1`.

Here's a [node.js article](https://nodesource.com/blog/semver-tilde-and-caret/):

> CARET: MAJOR ZERO Given Node.js community norms around the liberal
>   usage of major version 0, the second significant difference between
>   tilde and caret has been relatively controversial: the way it deals
>   with versions below 1.0.0. While tilde has the same behaviour below
>   1.0.0 as it does above, caret treats a major version of 0 as a special case. A caret expands to two different ranges depending on whether you
>   also have a minor version of 0 or not, as we'll see below: MAJOR AND
>   MINOR ZERO: ^0.0.Z → 0.0.Z Using the caret for versions less than
>   0.1.0 offers no flexibility at all. Only the exact version specified will be valid. For example, ^0.0.3 will only permit only exactly
>   version 0.0.3.

[**special-case for 0.x in ^ is very counter-inutitive and rage-inducing**](https://github.com/npm/node-semver/issues/79)